# How to prevent inferred type to be obj (or error)

Tags: generics, f#

the following code gives me some headache

```
type Config() = class end
type ProgressA<'a>(v: 'a) = class end
type DoneA<'a>(v:'a) = class end

type Foo () = class end

type ProgressX = ProgressA<Foo>
type DoneX = DoneA<Foo>

let somethingElse = 1

type Foo with
    static member inline Validate (_:Config) (p:ProgressX) : Option<ProgressX> = Some p


let inline validatex c p =
    (^T : (static member Validate: ^V -> ^P -> Option<ProgressA< ^T>>) c, p)

let p1: ProgressX = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
let v1: Config = Unchecked.defaultof<_>

let c = validatex v1 p1
```

because the inferred type of `c` is `Option<ProgressA<obj>>`. However the type I was expecting is `Option<ProgressA<Foo>>`.

If I change this the definition of `validatex` from

```
let inline validatex c p =
    (^T : (static member Validate: ^V -> ^P -> Option<ProgressA< ^T>>) c, p)
```

to

```
let inline validatex c p =
    (^T : (static member Validate: ^V -> ProgressA< ^T> -> Option<ProgressA< ^T>>) c, p)
```

I will get an error at the call site

```
let c = validatex v1 p1
```

Telling that the method `Validate` can not be found for `p1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my goodness! I found the solution ...
In One word: Tuples!

The issue seems to be that the type inferrer only runs correctly in this scenario IF the params to the member function is a SINGLE tuple argument.

```
type Foo with
                                  //see the double parens
    static member inline Validate ((_:Config, p:ProgressX)): Option<ProgressX> = Some p

//And then you need a lot of parens here as well
let inline validatex c p =
    (^T : (static member Validate: (^V * ProgressA< ^T>) -> Option<ProgressA< ^T>>) ((c, p)))
```